# Handling database in Android

Tags: android, database

I have a database which I need to manage within a library.
The library is the only one who will have access to the data, while anyone else will need to access it through the library API.

Do I need to implement content provider for this or is this overkill as it will anyway only be accessed internally?
Is the second option doing everything in raw SQL and then adding a thin API above?
Is there any solution in between these which takes advantage of available wrappers but don't require implementation of ContentProvider (which as far as I understand is not necessary here)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service that is able to interact with the database. Your service will provide the API.